# OBJ_C Is it possible to get working days according to the country of user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, date

Is it possible to get working days according to the country of user.

Maybe an API or a Web service?

I've not found any tools to do that..

Thanks

Comment: you need to calculate the days , why you need the third party api ….

Comment: Because i need to get ONLY WORKING DAYS without weekend (ok) and mainly without public holiday according to the country where the user is.

Comment: so it will be too tricky… need to search...

Comment: Yes i know... i search :)

Comment: For information i found this web service http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to get public holidays from icalendar? In fact Icalendar display the holiday days according to the system lang !?